# Lightswitch Deployment (Visual Studio 2013) Tier-3 with No Authentication

Tags: authentication, deployment, lightswitch-2013

I am attempting to deploy a simple lightswitch application (HTML not Windows app) in VS 2013.  I have selected to not have authentication to make the testing easier.

The IIS server and the database server are on different machines.  I have followed the steps [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/03/23/deployment-guide-how-to-configure-a-web-server-to-host-lightswitch-applications.aspx) for server setup.

However, when I go to the website after publishing, I get this error:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

I went to the IIS server and made sure that only Windows authentication was enabled on the application that was sent over.  After reading another MS article on the 401 error, they recommended unchecking the Kernel Mode Authentication.  That only prompted a username/password request, which did not work.

What am I doing wrong here?  I assumed having no authentication setup in the deployment would make the website open to anyone on our network.  Not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem(s) with this one.

*Problem #1*
When I downloaded / installed Microsoft's Web Platform Installer on my IIS server, the LightSwitch application I was working on and several other seemingly random websites/apps in the IIS all had the Authentication settings disabled for every authentication type (Anon, Basic, Windows, Forms, etc.).  Had to go and Enable windows authenication on several websites.  Did not expect that...

*Problem #2*
HTML Client folder was not loaded on the machine for some reason.  Removed Lightswitch app from IIS and deleted the folder.  Created a package for install in VS2013 and then copied the zip file over to the IIS server.  Flawless install after that...  One thing to watch for it to change the default setting in IIS from 'default.htm' to 'default.aspx'.